# tutorial-like Java EE 6 sources

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6

I'd like to learn Java EE (version 6) and already read about the basics. My problem is that I don't have a concrete application I could work on.

Do you know any source which describes the development of a (mostly) full-featured Java EE 6 project, compareable to a tutorial? Alternatively, I could use a suggestion on a project which would be most suitable for Java EE 6. (running on GlassFish 3.1 btw.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start with the [Netbeans E-commerce tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/intro.html). Quoted from the intro page:

> ... you may find that this tutorial works
>   best as a companion to the [Java EE
>   Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/). For each tutorial unit, make
>   best use of the provided links to
>   relevant areas in the Java EE
>   Tutorial, as well as to other useful
>   resources.